# VBS script not found 800A004C Line:3 Char 1

Tags: vbscript

i cant open vbs file, i want to use for microsoft office 2013

```
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
outFile="qemu\qemu.cmd"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.Write "@ECHO OFF" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "pushd ""%~dp0""" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "rem cd qemu" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "start qemu.exe ^" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "-smbios type=1,manufacturer=Intel,version=1.01234,uuid=564d81c6-cd3a-                        d8e4-db29-756df139acb9 ^" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "-uuid 564d81c6-cd3a-d8e4-db29-756df139acb9 ^" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "-net nic,vlan=0 -net user,vlan=0 -redir tcp:1688::1688 ^" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "-m 350 ^" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "-hda Bios\kmsm4WOen.rom ^" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write ("-rtc base=" & Year(Now) & "-" & Month(Now) & "-" & Day(Now) & "T" &     Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute (Now) & ":" & Second (Now) & ",clock=host ^") & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "-name ""KMSmicro v4.0.WO-En IP-127.0.0.1-254:1688"" ^" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "-M pc ^" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "-L Bios" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "popd" & vbCrLf
objFile.Write "exit" & vbCrLf
objFile.Close
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return = WshShell.Run ("qemu\qemu.cmd",,True)
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
obj.DeleteFile(outfile)
```

all my vbs file i can't open it
please tell me how to fix me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "800a004c - Path not found" in line 3 is thrown, because the sub folder `qemu` does not exist. `.CreateTextFile()` will create a file, but not the folder(s) in the file's path.

**P.S.:**

As the `.CreateTextFile()` and the `.Run()` use a relative path, 'having' a `qemu` folder somewhere won't help. It must be a sub folder of the current directory. The best way to avoid this problem is to use absolute/hard coded pathes.

```
outFile="a:\b\c d\qemu\qemu.cmd"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
...
outFile = """" & outFile & """"
Return = WshShell.Run (outFile,,True)
```

Comment: so how to fix, what should i do? i have qemu folder